# unable to figure out what is going on to the spring boot application on deployment on google app engine?

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

I am deploying spring boot application to the google app engine. after deployment, I am not able to access API.i have taken the logs and unable to figure out what is going on deployment? I haven't seen the message server started on port 8080 neither seen any error.

```
2019-05-05 15:34:01 default[20190505t202540]   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2019-05-05 15:34:01 default[20190505t202540]  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2019-05-05 15:34:01 default[20190505t202540]   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2019-05-05 15:34:01 default[20190505t202540]    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2019-05-05 15:34:01 default[20190505t202540]   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2019-05-05 15:34:01 default[20190505t202540]   :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)
2019-05-05 15:34:01 default[20190505t202540]
2019-05-05 15:34:02 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:34:02.600  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.s.b.u.UserManagementSystemApplication : Starting UserManagementSystemApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on a44cd614fb03 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2019-05-05 15:34:02 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:34:02.710  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.s.b.u.UserManagementSystemApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-05 15:34:05 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:34:05.744  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@9f70c54: startup date [Sun May 05 15:34:05 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-05-05 15:35:20 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:20.180  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e8df8f9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-05 15:35:25 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:25.367  INFO 1 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2019-05-05 15:35:26 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:26.843  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a9f633fa] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-05 15:35:27 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:27.542  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42a3fc34] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-05 15:35:27 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:27.754  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-05 15:35:27 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:27.799  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@115667d' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-05 15:35:27 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:27.848  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67789ee6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-05 15:35:28 default[20190505t202540]  2019-05-05 15:35:28.273  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Comment: It looks like that the log message is not printed. What is your log level? Can you provide the `logback-spring.xml`?

Comment: not have  logback-spring .xml in project.i am beginner in spring boot.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html because it looks like that your logging is not set up and the message is just not printed.

Comment: i am using app engine flexible environment and internally it runs jar